# What is preventing my code from checking the number of pushbutton values for a correct/wrong answer?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

My code is supposed to generate a random number and then display it in binary using four LEDs. After you press it, it waits for two seconds before checking your number of pushbutton presses to see if they equal the random number, and it turns the green/red LED on accordingly and restarts the loop.

It doesn't do that, and also it counts multiple pushes if you keep the button pressed in, since it reads the pushbutton as being "on".

Code:

```
//VARIABLES:
const int ledPin1 = 2;
const int ledPin2 = 3;
const int ledPin3 = 4;
const int ledPin4 = 5;
const int buttonPin = 6;        //push button
const int ledPincorrect = 8;   //green LED that switches on for correct answer
const int ledPinfalse = 9;    //red LED that switches on for wrong answer


int randomNumber = 0;
int buttonState = HIGH;
int buttonPushCounter = 0;             //counter for button presses
int lastButtonState = HIGH;             //previous state of the button
int getal;
int i;                              //for the ConvertBinary function, i serves as a variable for the LED's
unsigned long Timer;               //Timer, switches on after buttonstate = LOW, and after 2 seconds the game restarts
long lastDebounceTime = 0;         // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers
int ledState = HIGH;
int remember;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPincorrect, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPinfalse, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Timer = millis(); // unsigned long Timer = millis();

}
void loop()
{
  if (randomNumber == 0) {
    Serial.print("lets start with random");
    getal = random(1, 16);
    Serial.print("random is: ");
    Serial.println(getal);
    randomNumber = 1;
  }


   int remember = getal;
   for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
   remember = remember / 2;
      if (remember % 2 == 1){
       digitalWrite (i, HIGH);
      }
     else ((digitalWrite(i, LOW)));
    }


    // reading the button state



    // read the state of the switch into a local variable:
    int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    if (reading != lastButtonState) {
      lastDebounceTime = millis();
      if (reading == LOW) {                    // if (reading == LOW) ????
        buttonPushCounter++;
        Serial.println("on");
        Serial.print("number of button pushes:  ");
        Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
        Timer = millis();
        lastButtonState = buttonState;


      } else {
      // if the current state is LOW then the button wend from on to off:
      Serial.println("off");
    }


      if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    if (reading != buttonState) {
      buttonState = reading;
      lastButtonState = reading;
    }


    if (Timer >= 2000UL) {
      if (buttonPushCounter == getal) {
        digitalWrite(ledPincorrect, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPinfalse, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
      randomNumber = 0;
      buttonPushCounter = 0;
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(ledPinfalse, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(ledPincorrect, LOW);
        digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
      randomNumber = 0;
      buttonPushCounter = 0;
      }
}

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using serial communication to get some debug information out of your sketch? I see you've got some Serial calls in there, what does your output look like?

Comment: @Martin Carney

lets start with randomrandom is: 1

number of button pushes:  1

number of button pushes:  2

number of button pushes:  3

number of button pushes:  4

number of button pushes:  5

number of button pushes:  6

number of button pushes:  7

This is from one button press

Comment: Sounds like you have a debounce problem. I'd recommend making a simple sketch (e.g. with just one button and one LED) just to get your debounce code working the way you expect it to, then bring that over into your program as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the simplest issue in your code:

```
Timer = millis();
...
if (Timer >= 2000UL) {
...
}
```

After 2000 ms this is always true (for about 49 days)?

Cheers!

Please format your code if you expect anybody to take the time to read it and help.